# Can I use InputStreamResource to return an image as ByteArray into a Spring application?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am working on a **Spring Boot** backend application.

I have to retrieve a jpg image from a BLOB field on my database and return it to the frontend.

Searching online I have found this tutorial about how the controller should return a file to display: http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/032-return-file-from-spring-rest-webservice/

As you can see in the previous tutorial it do something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/pdf")
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> downloadPDFFile()
        throws IOException {

    ClassPathResource pdfFile = new ClassPathResource("pdf-sample.pdf");

    return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .contentLength(pdfFile.contentLength())
            .contentType(
                    MediaType.parseMediaType("application/octet-stream"))
            .body(new InputStreamResource(pdfFile.getInputStream()));
}
```

So, it is returning a **InputStreamResource** object wrapped into a **ResponseEntity**.

In the past I do it using a standard Java **array of bytes**. Reading the documentation I found that **InputStreamResource** is a specific Spring object: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/InputStreamResource.html

So, from what I have understand, I have the standard Java **InputStream** type that is an abstract class that is is the superclass of all classes representing an input stream of bytes (so something like as I done in the past). Then the **InputStreamResource** (used in the previous tutorial) is a specific **Resource** implementation of the **InputStream**.

Reading the documentation **Resource** is a Spring interface used to describe any type of resources (so images, files, etcetc).

So my doubt is this **InputStreamResource** the right choice to return a **JPEG files** to my front-end application as byte array?

I have this doubt because in the official documentation I read:

> Should only be used if no other specific Resource implementation is
>   applicable. In particular, prefer ByteArrayResource or any of the
>   file-based Resource implementations where possible.

Is it a good solution?

Comment: According to the documentation., if the read is a single use one InputStreamResource can be used. Cheers.

Comment: what do you mean as a "single use"?

Answer (score 7):

In general it is a good idea to *stream* your results back to the client.  The simple reason for that is that images and attachments are getting larger.  When you return a byte array, you have to have all of those bytes in memory at once.  That introduces you to an accidental denial of service incident if your image or attachment you are sending is too large to be in memory at once.

General Guidelines:

- If there is a better resource type, use that.  In your case you can just return your `ClassPathResource` in your response entity.
- There's also a `FileSystemResource` to return a file on disk
- Use `InputStreamResource` if there isn't already another resource type.  Example is returning blob content

Example of how to use the `InputStreamResource`:

```
    return new InputStreamResource(blob.getPayload().openStream()) {
        @Override
        public long contentLength() {
            return blob.getMetadata().getContentMetadata().getContentLength();
        }
    };
```

I would caution against the lazy thinking of returning a byte array.  It should only be considered if your response sizes are about 1MB or less.

Comment: A blob field is different. Blob is a JDBC resource that is closed on transaction-end. Since streaming the content happens after transaction-end the jdbc-stream is closed and nothing else returned than a IOException (or SQLException respectivly).

Comment: The Spring Infrastructure has support for handling that--however in your case you may need to create an actual object that extends `InputStreamResource` to close the stream, response, and connection objects depending on your DB vendor.  Not all DB vendors are equal here.

Comment: You get me wrong. All bytes must already be **transported** to the browser before the thread leaves the downloadPDFFile-method! AFAIK this is not possible in spring! In avoiding a byte[]-buffer and pointcuts the only way I found was to use the outputstream of the ServletResponse. Should I construct a Github project presenting the problem?

Comment: Probably.  I know the code above works in our case.

Comment: am I going crazy? `InputStreamResource` doesn't have a `contentLength()` method to override in Spring, it just needs the `InputStream`

Comment: The method is defined in the AbstractStreamResource, and we implemented it in the example code.  InputStreamResource handles the streaming part for you, but you do need to help it understand how many bytes will be sent.  Also keep in mind that the answer was written at a particular point in time.  If the API changes afterwards, you need to adapt.